# Unity and vuforia can't get 3D character to spawn

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to get Unity and Vuforia to work together with spawning a 3D object on a targeted AR image. I try it thru my webcam and everything is settled. When I put my AR target image in front of the camera, a 3D object is supposed to spawn in the camera. In tutorials and forums everyone talks about checking two things in the ARcam inspector called: Load databasename and another called Activate.

The problem is that I'm stuck in is that an update took these choices away from the program. And I guess it is replaced with something else somewhere in Unity. The part where I want to load the 3D object when I cam the targeted image. So my question is: Is there anyone out there who work with this and know how do I activate the function? Cause I can't find anything in forums or elsewhere. Could be that the update is rather new, but every tutorial is based on the previous version of Unity.

Also, when I check the console log, it reacts to the target image and when I move it away it says "lost" so I know that part works. But as I said before, nothing spawns on it. And I followed a tutorial where it works in the previous version of Unity, therefore I don't think there is any problems with sizes of the target or the 3D object.

Comment: Do you see the 3D object on the `ImageTarget` before you press Play in the Editor? If not, problem is coming from your side.

Comment: Yes i do. And everything seems alright but i cannot "check" the "activate" mark in the ARcam settings as they do in the description. Its removed in latest update. And i dont know if it should be auto fixed instead or if i have to edit that somewhere else.

Comment: Is your 3D object attached to the `ImageTarget` as a child in the Hierarchy?

Comment: Yes it is. Im going to try with Another imagetarget and see what gives

Comment: Could you share a sample project? Or make a screenshot of your `ARCamera` and `ImageTarget` GameObject's.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/S2GttEz https://imgur.com/a/6saPunR https://imgur.com/a/16AHPE2 https://imgur.com/a/MG7yS0z As you can see in this project, a new imagetarget the 3d object spawns, but not according to the imagetarget, just zoomed infront of my face... the difference between the last project and this is that now i get the 3d object spawned.. that is something i guess.

Comment: In the first image you have a `test3_base`. Is that ticked? I think not, tick it and also it will show all the images from your dataset.

Comment: Also your cactus is not attached to the `ImageTarget` as you can see in your last image. Make it a child of the `ImageTarget`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your accurate observations. It works now. Took me some tests to figure those simple things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ashamed, I forgot to put the picture as a child under the camera. Thank you for all the comments.